# How to find a total year sales from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, sum

I have this dictionary, and when I code for it, I only have the answer for June, May, September. How would I code for the months that are not given in the dictionary? Obviously, I have zero for them.

```
{'account': 'Amazon', 'amount': 300, 'day': 3, 'month': 'June'}

{'account': 'Facebook', 'amount': 550, 'day': 5, 'month': 'May'}

{'account': 'Google', 'amount': -200, 'day': 21, 'month': 'June'}

{'account': 'Amazon', 'amount': -300, 'day': 12, 'month': 'June'}

{'account': 'Facebook', 'amount': 130, 'day': 7, 'month': 'September'}

{'account': 'Google', 'amount': 250, 'day': 27, 'month': 'September'}

{'account': 'Amazon', 'amount': 200, 'day': 5, 'month': 'May'}
```

The method I used for months mentioned in the dictionary:

`year_balance=sum(d["amount"] for d in my_dict) print(f"The total year balance is {year_balance} $.")`

Comment: Please be a bit more elaborate. Why do you need the other months if you are only looking for the year total anyway? Also, check out defaultdict in collections, see my answer

Comment: @kakben for summery of the whole year

Comment: You are writing that you have this dictionary. Do you actually have a list of them, or what do you mean?

Comment: @kakben Yes that is

Answer (score 0):

```
import calendar

months = calendar.month_name[1:]
results = dict(zip(months, [0]*len(months)))

for d in data:
    results[d["month"]] += d["amount"]

# then you have results dict with monthly amounts
# sum everything to get yearly total
total = sum(results.values())
```

Comment: Thank you, when I run it it is said that there is a problem, the ivalid syntax, with +=.

Comment: it works on my machine :-/

Comment: @eolcos works for me too. Probably a typo?

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
from collections import defaultdict
mydict = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
print(mydict["January"])
```

Also, given the comments you have written, is this what you are looking for?

```
your_list_of_dicts = [
    {"January": 3, "March": 5},
    {"January": 3, "April": 5}
]

import calendar
months = calendar.month_name[1:]

month_totals = dict()
for month in months:
    month_totals[month] = 0
    for d in your_list_of_dicts:
        month_totals[month] += d[month] if month in d else 0

print(month_totals)
```

> {'January': 6, 'February': 0, 'March': 5, 'April': 5, 'May': 0, 'June': 0, 'July': 0, 'August': 0, 'September': 0, 'October': 0, 'November': 0, 'December': 0}

Comment: Thank you,in my situation I have May, June and September. 

therefore, I have this
 get_sum  = lambda my_dict, month: sum(d['amount']
for d in my_dict if d['month'] == month)
total_June = get_sum(my_dict, 'June')
total_May  = get_sum(my_dict, 'May' )
total_September = get_sum(my_dict, 'September' )
but for the other months it is 0, how could I include it into the code you gave?

Comment: Please update your question to reflect this information. Use code so it is readable. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can read the following blog regarding the usage of dictionaries and how to perform calculations.

[5 best ways to sum dictionary values in python](https://blog.finxter.com/5-best-ways-to-sum-dictionary-values-in-python/)

This is on of the examples given in the blog.

```
wages = {'01': 910.56, '02': 1298.68, '03': 1433.99, '04': 1050.14, '05': 877.67}
total = sum(wages.values())
print('Total Wages: ${0:,.2f}'.format(total))
```

Here is the result with 100,000 records.

[Result with 100,000 records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pf37.png)

Comment: Thank you, but that is not really relevent to this particular question. In the example they have less data

Comment: Irrespective of the amount of the data, the function should still work. 
The amount of data is just for illustration purpose. 
It should work even if you larger dataset.
I don't see any limitations.
Could you please elaborate on what exactly you are looking for?
Thank you!

Comment: I need to up up only particular key and value in each line. For example, all of the "amount".
Then, also I need to compare rows of "amount" + "month"